# Doesn't exist in the namespace c# wpf

Tags: c#, namespaces, hamburger-menu

I found something like Hamburger menu (MahApp on Nuget) and when im trying to set it to my project I got error:

> The name "MainViewModel" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:Hermes".   Hermes  C:\Program
>   Files\P4\Hermes\Hermes\ViewModel\MainWindow.xaml

In `d:DataContext = "{ d:DesignInstance local:MainViewModel }">`

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

Same with

> The name "SelectedItemToContentConverter" does not exist in the
>   namespace "clr-namespace:Hermes". Hermes  C:\Program
>   Files\P4\Hermes\Hermes\ViewModel\MainWindow.xaml

```
<local:SelectedItemToContentConverter x:Key="SelectedItemToContentConverter" />

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Hermes"
```

Both files: SelectedItemToContentConverter.cs and MainViewModel.cs are in the main project folder and have set `namespace Hermes`

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Is Hermes the full namespace and declared in the same assembly? Have you tried to rebuild the whole solution?

Comment: Assembly name: Hermes, Default namespace: Hermes. I tried to rebuild it and still that 2 errors